# Magento how to re-index product prices programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to re-index product prices after update in my product price but it's not working showing me old price in product list page. I am using this code

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$process->reindexAll();
```

I also tried this one

```
$reindex = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(2);
$reindex ->reindexAll();
```

But it's not working. I have tried from by this command

> php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price

It's working fine showing me updated prices.

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: i am using magento enterprise 1.14.2.4